# Is it possible to apply multiple cell formats when writing to a cell with xlsxwriter?

Tags: python, export-to-excel, xlsxwriter

I am new to xlsxwriter so any help is appreciated. I am trying to apply multiple cell formats to a cell within xlsxwriter and after looking around I did not see any information showing that this is possible but wanted to ask here and be sure.

Snippet of my code:

```
wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
ws1 = wb.add_worksheet()
calign = wb.add_format()
calign.set_align('center')
wrap = wb.add_format()
wrap.set_text_wrap()

ws1.write(0, 0, 'Username', calign, wrap)
```

It gives me the error:

```
TypeError: write_string() takes at most 5 arguments (6 given)
```

I understand the error in that I am giving it 1 more argument than it can take. However is there a function in xlsxwriter that is similar to easyXF in xlwt?

Example of easyxf function utilized in writing cell that applies multiple cell formats:

```
format = xlwt.easyxf('alignment: horiz centre, wrap on')
ws1.write(0,0,'Text', format)
```

I am utilizing xlsxwriter for the conditional formatting feature so switching to xlwt is not an option unless the cell formats become more important than the conditional formatting.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After looking into [source](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter) and [documentation](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/format.html#format), I have to say I'm afraid it is **not possible** to specify multiple cell formats, or join multiple formats into a single `Format` class.

You **have to add a new format**:

```
new_format = wb.add_format()
new_format.set_align('center')
new_format.set_text_wrap()

ws1.write(0, 0, 'Username', new_format)
```

FYI, there is a [`write_rich_string()`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/worksheet.html#write_rich_string) method also, which allows multiple formats - but I don't think this is what you are looking for since it would apply multiple formats to different parts/fragments of  a string.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer provided what I needed in terms of adding various alignment formatting to the cells. I have not tried it with every type of formatting available so I cannot speak to colors and such. I appreciate the response. Thanks again.